# Assumption on Runge-Kutta-Method

Tags: numerical-methods

I think I missed a crucial step concerning Runge-Kutta-methods. If a RK-method is given by its Butcher-table, is it necessary to have $\sum_{j = 1}^s a_{ij} = c_i$?

In class we discussed, that a consistent RK-method (we characterized this via $\sum_{i = 1}^s b_i = 1$) is autonomization invariant if the above condition is satisfied. Wikipedia states that every consistent RK-method fulfills this, but I do not see why this should be the case.

Can someone help me out on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

There are two ways to solve an ODE of form
$$
\mathbf y'(t) = \mathbf f(t, \mathbf y(t))\\
\mathbf y(t_0) = \mathbf y_0
$$
using some Runge-Kutta method. The first one is to apply RK method directly to the system. That method would use all its Butcher tableau.

The other one is to convert the system to an autonomous one via
$$
\mathbf Y(s) = \begin{pmatrix}t(s)\\ \mathbf y(s)\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf Y'(s) = \mathbf F(\mathbf Y(s)) \equiv \begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mathbf f(\mathbf Y(s))\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf Y(t_0) = \begin{pmatrix}t_0\\ \mathbf y_0\end{pmatrix}
$$
If we apply the same RK method to an autonomous system we get
$$
\mathbf K_i = \mathbf F\left(\mathbf Y_n + h \sum_j a_{ij} \mathbf K_j\right)\\
\mathbf Y_{n+1} = \mathbf Y_{n} + h \sum_j b_j \mathbf K_j
$$
Note, no $c_j$ coefficient was used. Let's expand the last relations in terms of old $t$ and $\mathbf y$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}r_i\\ \mathbf k_i\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mathbf f\left(t_n + h\sum a_{ij} r_j, \mathbf y_n + h\sum a_{ij} \mathbf k_j\right)\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mathbf f\left(t_n + h\sum a_{ij}, \mathbf y_n + h\sum a_{ij} \mathbf k_j\right)\end{pmatrix}
\\
\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+1}\\ \mathbf y_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}t_{n}\\ \mathbf y_{n}\end{pmatrix}
+ h \begin{pmatrix}\sum b_j r_j\\ \sum b_j \mathbf k_j\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}t_{n} + h\\ \mathbf y_{n}+ h\sum b_j \mathbf k_j\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that every $r_j = 1$. Also $\sum b_j = 1$ for every RK method. If the condition is not met, it simply would not approximate the original ODE, hence won't work. We arrived at a method that has form of a standard RK method, but with coefficients $c_i$ evaluated from $a_{ij}$
as
$$
c_i = \sum_j a_{ij}.
$$

I think one calls an RK method consistent if it stays the same whenever it is applied to the original problem or to its autonomization. So we see that RK method is consistent iff $c_i = \sum_j a_{ij}$.

This condition is exploited heavily when deriving RK methods of high orders. If a method attains order $p$ on autonomous problems then one can easily construct a method for nonautonomous problems simply by taking $c_i = \sum_j a_{ij}$. Taking other values for $c_i$ could not raise method order, since on autonomous problems the order still would be $p$ exactly.